# global and local javascript scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Why is it that the global variable is not recognized in this function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id_f = document.getElementById('f');

function foo()
{
id_f.innerHTML=("text");
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are wrong. it is recognized.

Comment: Are you sure it is not being recognized? Can you check if you really have an element with id "f"? You might be confusing the errors.

Comment: Where in your html code do you have it placed and what browser are you using to test with?

Comment: if you want it global why you added var ?

Comment: Are you sure that the variable contains the expected value(the desired element). Maybe the element is unknown when you initialize the variable.

Answer (score 3):

The `.getElementById()` function returns `null` if no matching element is found, which is not an error but if your `id_f` variable is `null` it doesn't have an `.innerHTML` property and that will give an error.

Even if there is a matching element in your page source it will not be found unless the script is run *after* the element is actually parsed. So your script needs to be somewhere after the element in the source (e.g., just before the closing `</body>` tag), or you need to add an onload or document.ready type handler and run your code from there.

(What do you get if you add `console.log(id_f)` or `alert(id_f)` to the beginning of your function?)

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly the problem.  I just started working with javascript so I appreciate the answers without being condescending.